# Old movie with aliens that look like humans except they have only two splayed toes

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The movie concerns aliens that look like normal humans, except they have only two splayed toes. They are living on Earth as normal humans. Don't remember much of the plot, except that their toes give them away.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: The aliens in The Brother from Another Planet had three toes.  Google for pictures.   The aliens in the 1996 movie The Arrival had weird legs and feet.  In both cases the aliens are hiding out as humans.  Any chance you're thinking of one of those?

Comment: If you don't remember a plot, are you sure it wasn't a documentary? Having only two splayed toes sounds like the real mutation [ectrodactyly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectrodactyly), and there's [at least one tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadoma) where a significant minority have a dominant form of it.

Comment: @DoscoJones I immediately thought of The Brother From Another Planet (which I love even though it's basically rubbish :-). But only one scene in the whole film shows the brother's feet (at the beginning after he's just regrown his leg) and as you say he has three toes not two.